# JOIN tables wp_postmeta and wp_woocommerce_order_items

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm a newbie in MySQL and I still can't get my head around JOIN tables.

I'm making an online store and I need to generate email reports of the ordered item together with some custom fields from the products.

In my database my products reside in `wp_posts`, and then I have custom fields in the `wp_postmeta`, now and I would like to see the relationship of it on the `wp_woocommerce_order_items` table.

Can someone show me how it can be done?

Comment: first please show what the content of `wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_woocommerce_order_items` we just can't imagine it..

Comment: basically i needed to fetch these: 1. two meta values from wp_postmeta (_locator, _stock), item name, and _qty from order_itemmeta

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to JOIN the `wp_woocommerce_order_items` and `wp_woocommerce_order_itemsmeta` tables because the meta table contains the meta key `_product_id` which matches the product's `post_id`.

Something like this should work (edited based on the required fields):

```
SELECT orders.order_item_name, orders.qty, locator.meta_value AS 'locator', stock.meta_value AS 'stock' 
FROM wp_postmeta locator

JOIN ( 
    SELECT items.order_item_name AS 'order_item_name', qty.meta_value AS 'qty',  product_id.id AS 'id' 
    FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` qty
    JOIN (
        SELECT order_item_id, meta_id, meta_key, meta_value AS 'id'     
        FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` 
        WHERE meta_key = '_product_id' 
        ) AS product_id
    ON qty.order_item_id = product_id.order_item_id
    JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_items` items
    ON product_id.order_item_id = items.order_item_id
    WHERE qty.meta_key = '_qty'
    ) AS orders
ON locator.post_id = orders.id

JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = '_stock'
    ) AS stock
ON locator.post_id = stock.post_id

WHERE locator.meta_key = '_locator';
```

Comment: This is probably the closest to my intention. How do you change this so that I am able to return rows with specific columns?

Comment: I updated the SQL statement based on your comment about needing  wp_postmeta (_locator, _stock), item name, and _qty.